# k2 json output not as expected

Tags: json, joomla, k2

i have a website in joomla using k2 and i am utelizing json output using ?format=json whitch has been working fine up antil yesterday were it randomly giving me a warning error on the json output before the json starts:

```
<br /><b>Warning</b>:  Creating default object from empty value in <b>/var/www/example.com/components/com_k2/views/itemlist/view.json.php</b> on line <b>149</b><br />
```

i cant find any thing anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Hi, i have same problem.
Have you solved?

Comment: i have a solution that helped me i turned error reporting to system default

Comment: me too. but i think that it will lost when k2 will be update. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In json.php line 149, you need to create the object before assigning a value

```
  //Category K2 plugins
  $category->event = new stdClass();
  $category->event->K2CategoryDisplay = '';
```

This have been already solve the problem in the the future release. Fix on github